# cloudinary images works well with img tag in laravel 8 locally but not on heroku/production -- img displays blank on heroku

Tags: laravel, image, heroku, src, cloudinary

I tried displaying uploaded images from cloudinary but it wasn't showing using the below

`<img style="width:auto" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hrwev09ub/image/upload/v1637132013/dnpic_1637127942.png">`

before now i tried the img tag above actually worked locally but not through heroku, because on heroku what i could see on checking the code source is the below

`<img style="width:auto" src="dnpic_1637127942.png">`

i am using Laravel 8 with cloudinary on heroku host -- can someone assist me with way out or refer me to a solution tips please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Danny and I work on Cloudinary's Developer Support team.

I've not had a lot of experience with deploying to Heroku, so I'm unable to speak on why the src is stripping out the `https://res.cloudinary.com/hrwev09ub/image/upload/v1637132013` part, however I do notice that the full image path results in a 404.

Could you please let me know what happens when you try to reference the sample image (https://res.cloudinary.com/hrwev09ub/image/upload/sample.jpg) without specifying `style=width:auto`?

It may also help to confirm you've followed all the steps on Heroku's documentation about using Cloudinary, available here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary

Thanks,
-Danny

Comment: Thanks Danny. Actually, using "https://res.cloudinary.com/hrwev09ub/image/upload/sample.jpg" works well on localhost with complete path being displayed but only displays filename on production. i have tried so many online responses to no avail.